# Generate random number with Node.js page

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using Javascript node express, I'm trying to create a page that loads a random number every time. However, this sends me a 500 server error notification and I'm not sure why.

```
app.get('/random-number',function(req,res){
      res.type('text/plain');
      var randomnumber=Math.random();
      res.send(randomnumber);
});
```

Comment: Did you look at the console that you're running your server from? What error did it report there?

Comment: What web framework are you using? What is the error? What page did you hit? What have you done to attempt to fix this yourself? Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions.

Comment: The random number generation is not the key here, I guess you would have the same issues with `randomnumber = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The res.send() function won't allow you to send integers in the response body.

From the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) :

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array.

As such:

```
app.get('/random-number',function(req,res){
      res.type('text/plain');
      var randomnumber=Math.random();
      res.send(''+randomnumber);
});
```

Worked for me.

Or, of course:

```
app.get('/random-number',function(req,res){
      res.type('text/plain');
      var randomnumber=Math.random();
      res.send(randomnumber.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const randomNumber = require('./randomNumber');


app.use((req, res) => {
  const x = randomNumber.random();
  res.send(` ${x}`);
});

app.listen(1234, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 1234');
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.